# write a function to create a vector testing two conditions at the same time (R version 3.0.2)

Tags: r

Hello everyone i am new to r and i want to write a function so it can create a vector containing two letters a and b testing two conditions at the same time:
my code starts like this :

```
test<- function(N) {
  x<- NA
  for(i in 1:N) {
    x[i]<- runif(1,0,1)
    if(x[i]<0.5) {
      f<- 'a'
    } else {
      f<- 'b' 
    }
    print(f)
  }
}
```

from now on i want to add a or b values to f using append (i think) checking a double condition every time 
the first condition has to do with length(which(f=='a')-length(which(f=='b') 
and the second has to do with x
Many thanks in advance!!!
I would like to thank you for your response and i am going to explain my problem better . 
The first value of my vector lets say f will be 'a' if x<0.5 where x is from runif(0,1) and x is different every time. if x>0.5 the first value will be 'b'. The second value will be added to the first under the same condition and so on . The matter is that every time i care about this : number of 'a's-number of 'b's because when 'a's-'b'>2 then i have to change the way i add a or b to f like that : if x<0.2 then a else b . the result will be sth like this 
f<- a,b,a,a,a,b,a,b 
f i use the sample command how am i supposed to count the number of 'a's and the number of 'b's every time i add one value to f? the important thing here is that if their difference exceeds 2 then i will have to change the sample possibility.
Hello again, after you have helped me i tried again to solve the problem . The code i wrote is :

```
set.seed(100)
N<- 20
x<- rep(NA, 20)
tmp<- rep(FALSE, 20)
for(i in seq(N)) {
 for(j in seq(N)) {
x[i]<- runif(1)
y[i]<- t[i] < 0.5
if((2 * sum(tmp) - i + 1) < -2) {
y[i]<- t[i]<0.2
}
}
}
```

The possibility for a (TRUE is 0.5) but when the loop meets this condition ((2 * sum(tmp) - i + 1) < -2)  or ((2 * sum(tmp) - i + 1) > 2) I want the loop to continue with either 0.8 possibility in the first case or 0.2 in the second.
the result from my code is this

```
    [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
    [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I am certainly wrong . But how ? What can i do ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's not very clear what you are asking for, but have a look at `?base::Logic`.   You are likely looking for `&&`.   Also have a look at `?any` and `?all`

Comment: Also, `for (i in i)` is not good. Try `for (j in i)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sample(c("a","b"), 10, replace=TRUE)
[1] "a" "a" "b" "a" "a" "a" "b" "a" "a" "b"
```

What you are doing is just random sampling from "a" and "b" with 50/50 chance and replacement. (At least that is how I understand the pseudo code with [0,.5) giving "a" and [.5,1] giving "b")

---

*code golf version*: `sample(c("a","b"),10,T)`

Answer (score 2):

No need to do a loop heere , use `ifelse`, it is vectorized. For example:

```
set.seed(1)
N <- 5
ifelse(runif(N,0,1)<0.5,'a','b')
[1] "a" "a" "b" "b" "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to use indexing to create the vector:

```
c("b", "a")[(runif(10, 0, 1) < 0.5) + 1]
# [1] "b" "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "a" "b" "a" "b"
```

**Update**

Based on the new information you provided, I suppose you're looking for this:

```
N <- 10 # number of runs
tmp <- rep(FALSE, 10)
for (i in seq(N)) {
  # the probability for TRUE is either 0.2 if the number of a's minus
  # the number of b's exceeds 2 or 0.5 otherwise
  tmp[i] <- runif(1) < (0.2 + 0.3 * ((2 * sum(tmp) - i + 1) <= 2))
}
# tmp is a logical vector, TRUE indicates a, FALSE indicates b
f <- c("b", "a")[tmp + 1]
```

The difference between the number of `b`s and `a`s (represented by `FALSE` and `TRUE`) is counted in `2 * sum(tmp) - i + 1`. Since the vector `tmp` is initialized with `FALSE` values only, `sum(tmp)` represents the number of `a`s. The variable `i` represents the number of sampled values + 1 (e.g., in the second run of the loop, `i` is `2` and one value has been created in the run before). Hence, the number of `b`s is represented by `i - 1 - sum(tmp)`.

Comment: @Яaffael Of course, the `sample` command is the best one for this task.

Comment: if i use the sample command how am i supposed to count the number of 'a's and the number of 'b's every time i add one value to f? the important thing here is that if their difference exceeds 2 then i will have to change the sample possibility.

Comment: @ Sven Hohenstein. Lots of thanks ! Thats exactly what i wanted. could you please tell me how you count the a's and b's every time? thanks again!

Comment: @user3014110 I added an explanation.

Comment: Sven, you're pushing it! I will have to update my answer and add a several sections explaining basic concepts of probability and the history of R PLUS how to use vectors - there's no way you can beat that. @user3014110: please take my answer, I promise to buy you a cake!

Comment: @ Sven . I got it thanks again ! Rafael maybe i didnt clarify form the beginning that i am new to r . i am sorry i cannot take your answer as it seems to solve half or less of my problem . And instead of buying me a cake you could share your wisdom and propose any material i could study to become better.. thanks for your time anyway

Comment: @user3014110: Oh, come on, User number 3014110, I am just kidding ;)

Comment: @ Sven Hohenstein . I have another problem here : the probability for true changes when the number of a's - the numbers of b's >2 to 0.2 and stays until (and if) the number of b's - the numbers of a's > 2 when it changes to 0.8. It is a way to keep the number of a's and b's to a balance. Any suggestions or any sources i could use ?